# How to search a custom object using one or more input pick list fields from a VF page and display the result(s) in a pageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-soql, pageblocktable, country-and-state

accept the input as strings (in an extension),
build &
execute the query,
populate a list element,
display the list.

Please give an example.

Comment: Please be more specific. Try adding some images of the search screen.

Comment: I have custom object which having some picklist fileds like state, district, mandal etc, I want to add that fields in visualforce page.  Based on the picklist values record should filter display in Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code block will help you search using two picklist --

```
<apex:page controller="searchObj ">
  <apex:form>
  <apex:pageblock>
  <apex:actionFunction name="dosearchaction" action="{!dosearch}" reRender="showId"/>
      <apex:pageBlockSection>

          <apex:selectList id="pick1" value="{!picklistval1}" size="1" required="true">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!value1}"/>
          </apex:selectList>

          <apex:selectList id="pick2" value="{!picklistval2}" size="1" required="true" onchange="dosearchaction();">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!value2}"/>
          </apex:selectList>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="showId">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objList}" var="item">
              <apex:column value="{!item.Id}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Name}"/>
          </apex:pageblockTable>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageblock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller :

```
public class searchObj {

public String picklistval1 {get;set;}
public String picklistval2 {get;set;}
public List<Object> objList{get;set;}

public searchAcc() {
    objList=new List<Object>();
}

public List<SelectOption> getvalue1(){

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = object.field1.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }       
    return options;
}

public List<SelectOption> getvalue2(){

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = object.field2.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }       
    return options;
}



public void dosearch(){

    objList = [Select Id, Name from object Where field1 =: picklistval1 and filed2=:picklistval2]; //change according to your criteria


}
}
```

Now,if you want to seacrh using more than two picklist then you have to chnage the `query` and shift the `onchnage` function on the last picklist

Comment: Hi,  I got it, Thank you so much, Can you explain , how to export the PageBlockTable data as pdf and Excel with a button here? so that I am very glad.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are the three input field, based on these field, result will be displayed after click on Search button.

**Code snippet for input field and Search button**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputLabel >InputField1 :
                        <apex:selectList value="{!object1.input1}" multiselect="false">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!inputList1}">
                            </apex:selectOptions>
                        </apex:selectList>
            </apex:outputLabel>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputLabel >InputField2 :
                        <apex:selectList value="{!object1.input2}" multiselect="false">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!inputList2}">
                            </apex:selectOptions>
                        </apex:selectList>
            </apex:outputLabel>
        </td
        <td>
            <apex:outputLabel >InputField3 :
                        <apex:selectList value="{!object1.input3}" multiselect="false">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!inputList3}">
                            </apex:selectOptions>
                        </apex:selectList>
            </apex:outputLabel>
        </td
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!doSearch}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Code snippet for display search result:**

```
<apex:pageBlock >
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> ID</th>
        <th> Name</th>
        <th> Amount</th>
        <th> Country</th>
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat var="rc" value="{!resultList}">
    <td >{!rc.ID} </td>
    <td >{!rc.Name} </td>
    <td >{!rc.Amount} </td>
    <td >{!rc.Country} </td>    
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
</apex:pageBlock >
```

**Apex: Controller**

```
public class SampleClass{

public String input1{get;set;}
public String input2{get;set;}
public String input3{get;set;}
public List<object1> resultList{get;set;}

public SampleClass(){}

    public doSearch(){
        String query = 'SELECT ID,NAME,AMOUNT,COUNTRY FROM object1 WHERE ';
        if(object1.input1 !=null){
        query += ' input1 ='+object1.input1;
        }
        if(object1.input2 !=null){
        query += ' input2 ='+object1.input2;
        }
        if(object1.input3 !=null){
        query += ' input3 ='+object1.input3;
        }
        resultList= Database.query(query);
    }

    public List<SelectOption> inputList1() {

            List<SelectOption> options =new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('','--NONE--'));
            if(object1.input1.getDescribe() != null){
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult serviceLineFieldDescription = object1.input1.getDescribe();
                for(Schema.PicklistEntry pcklstEntry : serviceLineFieldDescription.getPicklistValues()){
                    options.add(new SelectOption(pcklstEntry.getValue(),pcklstEntry.getLabel()));
                }
            }
            return options;
        }

    public List<SelectOption> inputList2() {

            List<SelectOption> options =new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('','--NONE--'));
            if(object1.input2.getDescribe() != null){
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult serviceLineFieldDescription = object1.input2.getDescribe();
                for(Schema.PicklistEntry pcklstEntry : serviceLineFieldDescription.getPicklistValues()){
                    options.add(new SelectOption(pcklstEntry.getValue(),pcklstEntry.getLabel()));
                }
            }
            return options;
        }

    public List<SelectOption> inputList3() {

            List<SelectOption> options =new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('','--NONE--'));
            if(object1.input3.getDescribe() != null){
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult serviceLineFieldDescription = object1.input3.getDescribe();
                for(Schema.PicklistEntry pcklstEntry : serviceLineFieldDescription.getPicklistValues()){
                    options.add(new SelectOption(pcklstEntry.getValue(),pcklstEntry.getLabel()));
                }
            }
            return options;
        }
}
```

Hope It will help you!!Thank You-